# Querying across Oracle Schema's in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlplus, cx-oracle, tns

I can log onto my oracle instance using `sqlplus` with:

```
$ env | grep -E '(TWO|SID)'
TWO_TASK=TEST
$ sqlplus me/my_password@TEST
```

And then I can run the following query without problems:

```
select 
  persons.person.key AS id,
  persons.person.lname as lastname,
  persons.person.fname as firstname,
  sid.organizations.org_code as org,
  sid.organizations.division_code as division,
  sid.organizations.directorate_code as directorate,
  persons.person.status as status
from
   persons.person,
   sid.organizations
where
   persons.person.dept_id=sid.organizations.org_id;
```

However, in my python code, using `cx_Oracle`, with the following code (ie identical query):

```
def get_oracle( user, password, tns='TEST' ):
    db = cx_Oracle.connect( user, password, tns )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor

db = get_oracle( 'me', 'my_pass' )
db.execute("""
select
  persons.person.key AS id,
  persons.person.lname as lastname,
  persons.person.fname as firstname,
  sid.organizations.org_code as org,
  sid.organizations.division_code as division,
  sid.organizations.directorate_code as directorate,
  persons.person.status as status
from
   persons.person,
   sid.organizations
where
   persons.person.dept_id=sid.organizations.org_id;
""")
for r in db:
    pass
```

Results get the following error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I'm pretty sure my connection is fine, as other queries work okay.

Comment: Why do you believe this has anything to do with the tables existing in a different schema?  You have a semicolon at the end of the statement which is not part of a SQL statement (it is one way of telling SQL*Plus that you are done entering the SQL statement).  I also can't figure out why you have three double quote characters at the beginning and end of your string-- why not just use a single single-quote character to delimit the string just like you do with all the other strings in your code?

Comment: The 3 double quote characters is pretty standard for multi-line Python strings @Justin. The issue is the semi-colon as you describe.

Comment: thanks Justin, yep - just a silly typo!

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question, it's a silly typo with the semi-colon at the end of the query!